# Partition to run a Windows program

Tags: boot, partitioning, windows

I like using Linux Ubuntu and have few problems. However, I need to run an exam marking program that will only run on Windows. How can I create a Windows partition without wiping and re-installing Linux Ubuntu?

Help is appreciated.

Comment: Try to run the application using the PlayOnLinux application. It allows you to use Windows programs with Ubuntu. No Windows install needed.

Comment: I heard someone say it's possible if you use gparted to create and format a partition to NTFS before the installation. During installation you direct it to the partition's path when it asks you to select a disk or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is 'create a virtual machine' within your current linux install.

If you are on Ubuntu you already have a number of good choices for 'virtualisation', here is the ubuntu link https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VirtualMachines

What you will need is the following.

Install one of the virtual machine software systems from the above link (virtualBox comes to mind as being a fairly easy one, but I recal that XEN and Qemu are available).

A copy of your 'guest' OS, in your case a copy of windows.

Then you will need to start your virtual machine software and tell it to create a new virtual machine. Then it is just a simple matter of following the instructions for creating the machine - in effect you use your windows install disk to install a copy o windows inside your running ubuntu.

Some terms you may need to get your head around.

Host OS : for you this is the main OS on your pc (ie ubuntu, the system that comes on when you turn on your computer)

Guest OS : the OS that you want to run inside your virtual machine (ie windows)

Bridge : you can get you host and guest to communicate, share internet connections, share a HDD (you may need to set up samba on your host to 'serve' a shared disk to windows).

One annoyance.
If you are running a dual boot system, you can't turn your currently installed version into a virtual machine, which is a pain as mostly when you buy a pc you don't get a copy of the OS.

Other option.
If you have an 'old' windows pc sitting around you can use that and 'remotely log onto it' - it takes a bit of setting up (ie time / security etc). Maybe your employer can provide you with a remote logon to a pc for your requirements ?

Hope the above helps you out.

If you run into any problems during the creation of the virtual macine, check back on the ubuntu forums, here is a link to an ubuntu wiki page [first VM](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VirtualBox/FirstVM)